# iOS - Django Python - Oauth2

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build an authentication system for an iOS app. Those are the steps:

1. The user will log via Google oauth and will receive an auth code.
2. iOS app will send to BE this auth code and will exchange with an access token.
3. The BE will create a new token using Django Oauth Toolkit and send back to iOS app and will be stored into keychain.

Now the problem I have: When the app launches freshly (previously logged in),  I try to use `.onAppear` and inside I have `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn`, and make a call to Auth server that issued my token to verify if it is still active and renew it using the refresh token.

The url that I want to use is `/o/introspect/`, but is there any way to send the token without sending `client id` and `client secret`? I don't want them to be exposed on the iOS app.
Or should I create a new url that accepts only the token and verifies?

Thank you!

Comment: Normally you would send the access token to your back end and it would validate that. Then the client will automatically get a new access token, when required, using the refresh token.  If you want your back end to issue its own access token, it should do so based on the user's access token, not the auth code.  When the token from your back end expires (or when the app is re-opened) then the client can obtain a new token from your back end by supplying a valid access token once more.

Comment: Your back end shouldn't need to do anything with OAuth. It can simply validate the access token (Based on the JWT signature and KID) and then mint its own JWT and supply that to the client

Comment: @Paulw11 okay, i almost understand it. So right now I exchange the access code for access token from Google in my Auth Server and then I should generate my JWT and send back to iOS app. When the app make a request to Resources Server, it will send this JWT, right? But how the resources server validate it is real JWT from Auth server?

Comment: It can obtain the public key based on the KID claim in the JWT and then verify the JWT signature.  You ca also check for the expected AUD and SUB claims.  I would have to search, but I think Google even offers an endpoint that can validate a JWT for you.